# How to call custom helper function in filesystems

Tags: php, laravel

My situation is where i need to load `tenant_path()` inside the `filesystems.php` like the code below. it is for `tenant_path()` function located in `helpers.php` which is my custom helper class `App/Helpers/helpers.php`. the purpose is for dynamic path for different tenant.

My problem is `tenant_path()` is not loaded in `filesystems.php` but when i tried in middleware, controller and model its work.. seems like `tenant_path()` is not loaded yet in when Laravel run the `filesystems.php`. but how the `storage_path()` in `Foundation/helpers` works while my `tenant_path()` is not working in `filesystem.php`

Error show

> ```
> [ReflectionException]             
> Class path.tenant does not exist
> ```

Below is my code

**Filesystems.php**

```
'image' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/images/'.tenant_path()),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

**Helpers.php**

```
if (! function_exists('tenant_path')) {
    /**
     * Get the path to the tenant folder.
     *
     * @param  string  $path
     * @return string
     */
    function tenant_path($path = '')
    {
        return ""; //also not working
        return app()->make('path.tenant').($path ? DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.ltrim($path, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) : $path);
    }
}
```

**AppServiceProvider**

```
Tenanti::connection('company', function (TenantDomain $entity, array $config) {
            $config['database'] = env('TENANTI_DB_PREFIX')."_{$entity->id}";

            $this->app->bind('path.tenant', function () use ($entity) {
                return "{$entity->sub_domain}.".env('APP_DOMAIN');
            });

            return $config;
        });
```

**composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
        "files": ["app/Helpers/helpers.php"]
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours, I managed to solve it by resetting the filesystems config.. it seem filesystems already convert everything into array and only work on first initialisation. seem like hacky trick.. i dont know if it is the correct way or not..

my solution is where get filesystems config and traverse along the disks and append tenant_path with disks root.

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
//bind tenant_path with null string
$this->app->bind('path.tenant', function () {
    return "";
});

Tenanti::connection('company', function (TenantDomain $entity, array $config) {
    $config['database'] = env('TENANTI_DB_PREFIX')."_{$entity->id}";

    // bind with new tenant_path when there is switching connection
    $this->app->bind('path.tenant', function () use ($entity) {
        return "{$entity->sub_domain}.".env('APP_DOMAIN');
    });


    // hacky filesystems config
    $filesystems = config('filesystems');
    foreach ($filesystems['disks'] as $key => $disk) {
       if (!in_array($key, ['local', 'bepunct', 'public', 's3'])) {
            //replace with tenant_path
            $filesystems['disks'][$key]['root'] = $disk['root'].tenant_path();
       }
    }

    //reset filesystem with new tenant filesystems
    config()->set('filesystems', $filesystems);

    return $config;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel gives you an artisan command for this, just run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

This will execute 2 commands config:clear and config:cache, hope this helps.

Comment: nope.. i already tried those..  seems tenant_path() helper is not loaded yet in when Laravel run the filesystems.php..